# What is the purpose of registering a dataframe as a temporary view?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to understand why I would register a dataframe as a temporary view in pyspark.

Here's a dummy example

```
# Create spark dataframe
spark_df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, 'foo'),(2, 'bar'),],['id', 'txt'])

# Pull data using the dataframe
spark_df.selectExpr("id + 1")

# Register spark_df as a temporary view to the catalog
spark_df.createOrReplaceTempView("temp")

# Pull data using the view
spark.sql("select id + 1 from temp")
```

Whether I register the dataframe as a temporary view or not:

1. The data can only be accessed in this live spark session
2. I can use sql statements to query the data in both cases
3. Pulling data takes pretty much the same time (10K simulations, but I don't have a spark cluster yet, only my local machine).

**I am failing to see the benefits of storing a dataframe as a temporary view, but I see it in every introductory classes to pyspark. What am I missing?** Tks!!

Comment: sql itself is benefit for someone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL is quite a powerful language and many consider it beneficial in some cases.

Comment: Ok, so no other differences, it's about the ability to use SQL statements or not. Thanks for the answer.